# How to get the name of the last author?

Tags: excel, vba

I used the below code to get the last modified user name.

```
LastAuthor = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")
Range(Cells(I + 1, 4), Cells(I + 1, 4)) = LastAuthor
```

I am getting my name instead of the other users for every Excel file.

Comment: You probably want to be using `ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author")` instead

Comment: @Tom I did still the same thing

Comment: If you check "INFO" for the file, what does it show for "Last Modified By"?

Comment: yes, it does @RonRosenfeld

Comment: I don't understand your response.